# NSMutableArray issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can anyone explain why this code is breaking my app:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"recipeA", @"recipeA1", @"recipeA2", @"recipeA3",@"recipeA4",@"recipeA5",@"recipeA6",@"recipeA7",nil];

//these both break the app with invalid pointer type warnings
NSLog("What is 0: %@", [myArray objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog("What is the count: %i", [myArray count]);
```

Comment: removed tag 'xcode' http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot the `@` in front of the NSLog string:

```
NSLog(@"What is 0: %@", [myArray objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"What is the count: %i", [myArray count]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it had to be something like that.